# Number of inversions and unsortedness of the array

Tags: arrays

An array A[1:N] is said to be d-unsorted iff |k-rank(A[k])|<=d for 1<= k<= N.

And the number of inversions in an unsorted array A[1:N]

is the number of pairs (j,k) such that 1<=j< k<= N and A[k]< A[j].

eg. [2,4,1,5,3] has 4 inversions and it is 2-unsorted

My question is..can we relate the maximum number of inversions in an array to d?

Can we get a formula for finding the maximum number of inversions in an array 
knowing how much d-unsorted the array is?